# How can I shift a label storyboard to the right? Constraints are greyed out

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to shift over a label within my storyboard in xcode over to the right a few pixels. Is this possible through xcode?

I thought I would be able to do it through the storyboard but I am unable to add a label to the constraint as the constraint options are grayed out. When I select the element, I am also unable to change the size of the element.

Here's a picture of the label named Title: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYzzt.jpg

Comment: The image suggest a bug in Xcode just try restarting Xcode

Comment: @RaziTiwana Unfortunately that did not fix it

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to move the label over a few pixels using the right, left, up and down buttons.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu9Qc.jpg